# Power Apps Custom Forms not refreshing on edit/view

Tags: caching, sharepoint, refresh, powerapps

I have a Sharepoint list customized PowerApp, where if I am opening any item in view/edit mode - it will show me the data of the previously opened item. But when I refresh the browser, the data is correct.

I tried adding :- Refresh (DataSource) in the onsuccess property of the form,

[ turn "Off" the experimental data cache under Settings ]  - this is not available now.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Power Apps but not new to SQL and ASP so I had a similar challenge to overcome. After much scratching of my head, I settled on the LookUp approach:

```
If(1=1,
    LookUp(
            FMSVehicles,
            varSelectedVehicle.UniqueID = UniqueID,
            VehicleProfile.ProfileName
          ),
    
    varSelectedVehicle.VehicleProfile.ProfileName
  )
```

Since the result will always be true, the LookUp will ensure the latest value is always displayed.

As I said, I'm new to this, so it's probably going to be called out with performance issues, but my solution is not going to be huge so it fits my purpose.